# Basic compactness

Tags: general-topology

Okay, so this is my first glance at **compactness**. I've read the definition, but I'm strugling with an example (actually the introductory example) from my textbook. Here's the example: Let $S=(0,2)$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $A_{n}=(\frac{1}{n},3)$ If $0<x<2$, then by the Archimedian property, there exists a $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x$. Thus $x\in A_{p}$, and $\mathcal{F}=\{A_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover for $S$. However, if $\mathcal{G}=\{A_{1}, \ldots , A_{n_{k}}\}$ is any finite subfamily of $\mathcal{F}$, and if $m=\mathrm{max}\{n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}\}$, then

\begin{align*}
A_{n_{1}} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n_{k}} = A_{m} = \Big(\frac{1}{m},3\Big).
\end{align*}

It follows that the finite subfamily $\mathcal{G}$ is not an open cover of (0,2)

As you see, the author "just" assumes that it follows. The way I see it, is that if $m$ is an index of a finite set, then $\frac{1}{m}$ will never converge to zero, and therefore, it can not be a cover to $S$ at all.

In my book, the topic "compact set" is before metric spaces. Should I read and learn about metric spaces before compact sets ?

To me, it's a difficult topic (at least at this first glance), so if you know any good introductory to supplement with book, please don't hesitate to share.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting confused exactly, what you say is true, any finite cover cannot be a cover of $S$, which is precisely what they are trying to show ($S$ is not compact).

Comment: Okay. It was this statement I was confused about: The way I see it, is that if $m$ is an index of a finite set, then $\frac{1}{m}$ will never converge to zero, and therefore, it can not be a cover to S at all. But it turns out to be right, - thx!

Comment: Is it clear to you that $\mathcal{F}$ is an open cover of $S$ (it is), or is that the problem? It should be clear from the geometry that any finite subcollection of $\mathcal{F}$ cannot cover $S$. The number $m$ is not the index of a finite set, it is the index of a particular open interval, namely $(\frac{1}{m},3)$.

Comment: Ahhhh, - thank you very much. Now I see it. It was just that single thing I've missed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right. But don't think of that $m$ as an index, it is a bit more important than that. In this case whenever we take a finite sub collection of the given cover and take the union we get an $A_m$ where that $m$ is precisely the max of the indices of our finite collection $\{A_n\}$ and $1/m$ is never zero as you've noticed. So it's clear that any number in between $0$ and $1/m$ can never be in the union of the finite subcollection. And hence it can not be a subcover for our set.
And it would be good if you study some metric spaces before doing compactness(or even general topology). You just have to be familiar with some examples and concepts of open balls and open sets in metric spaces. That's enough for now I think..

Comment: Thanks. Regarding metric spaces, and where to start. Our department has decided to use "Analysis with an introduction to proof" by Steven R. Lay. In this textbook, compact sets is a section just before metric spaces. So it's not very connected. So for now, I'm a bit unsure what to do.